# XPages - Sorting a filtered view

Tags: xpages

I have a DominoView data source on my XPage that is filtered using a URL parameter so that only documents matching this parm are displayed.

The filtered documents then need to be sorted by the value of the second column (a status field). What would be the best approach to this?

The XPage is using jQuery Mobile for presentation and the documents would, ideally, be presented in a collapsible list with a separate collapsible  for each status value.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: do you use exactMatch on filtered value?

Comment: No, I've got keysExactMatch="false"

Comment: with exact match to false you can't get values sorted by second column right from the view. so the only option is to resort collection of data

Comment: Thanks for your advice. For this particular application requirement, this may be the way I need to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest one is to have that view sorted in the second column **too**. No extra code required. You can have multiple sorted columns which don't need to be adjacent. Then you can have better filter keys. E.g you have 4 sorted columns: you use an array with 1-4 elements as filter.  With 1 element it filters on the first column. With 2 elements it filters on the first and second column etc. The results are returned sorted by the remaining sorted columns

Comment: Does the view not need to be sorted by the first column to be able to filter by that column? From Designer Help...  keys="key(s)" (dominoView) Specifies keys for filtering the view. Each key (use an array for multiple keys) corresponds to a **sorted** column in the view in order.

Comment: I'm thinking I might have to re-sort the docs myself after filtering by the first column to get them into the correct order. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: You sort the view on the first **two** columns (or more if you like).  When you filter on the first one the returned documents will be sorted by the remaining sorted columns.  There can be as many sorted columns as you like. What you can't do is change the sort order on the fly.  With more sorted columns you can have more precise filters

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help your situation, but I was building a repeat with a view datasource that I needed to search based on a user's value I had stored in the sessionScope.  When performing the search, I lost the default sort I had in the view.  By adding sortColumn and sortOrder, I got the result I was looking for.

Here's a sample of the source;

```
    <xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView
        var="aprofiles"
        viewName="embAssessmentProfiles"
        sortOrder="ascending"
        sortColumn="apName">
        <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.searchFilter;}]]></xp:this.search>
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That will work fine when searching the view using a FT search, as in your example. However I need to display the view (filtered & sorted) rather than searching, as this is going to be used for locating a new document where the FT index has not yet been updated.