# Xpages: Keep view sort order when filtering on view

Tags: xpages

My Xpage has a dataView that points to a view which is sorted by employee name. One of the other fields in the employee view is their Location. I have a combobox in the header of the view that allows a user to subset to one location. When subsetted the correct employees appear, but the sort order is lost.

I have looked at a few answers in Stack overflow such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952598/xpages-sorting-a-filtered-view) and [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358319/xpages-viewpanel-searching-and-sorting) but cannot get them to work. I think the difference is that
I am not trying to filter on a value that is sorted.

Here is my code for the FT Search:

```
var tmpArray = new Array("");
var cTerms = 0;

//Geo Location Search
if(viewScope.key != null & viewScope.key != "" & viewScope.key != "All Locations" & viewScope.key != "--Select a Location--") {
             tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(FIELD HR_GeoLocation = " + viewScope.key + ")";}

qstring = tmpArray.join(" AND ").trim();
viewScope.queryString = qstring; // this just displays the query
return qstring // this is what sets the search property
```

The view's first field is the users last name, first name, descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FTSearch](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FTSEARCH_METHOD_COLLECTION_JAVA.html?lang=en) doesn't return found documents in view's order:

> The collection of documents that match the full-text query are sorted
>   by relevance, with highest relevance first.

Use an additional view which is categorized by Location and use Location as key in

- Filter by category name (categoryFilter) or
- Filter by column value
  (keys/keysExactMatch)

The columns after Location-column are the same as in your current view.